# How to add an event at eventStore.save?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm developing an OS X app with Swift.
If pressing the Add button and call the function "saveEvent()" on the screen for adding an event to the calendar, the error "unrecognized selector sent to instance" will appear.

It stops at eventStore.save and the event is not added.
How can I add an event?

```
import Cocoa
import EventKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    let eventStore:EKEventStore = EKEventStore()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let status = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: EKEntityType.event)
        if status == .authorized {
            print("success")
        }else if status == .notDetermined {
            eventStore.requestAccess(to: EKEntityType.event) { (granted, error) in
                if granted {
                    print("true")
                }else {
                    print("false")
                }
            }
        }
        saveEvent()
    }

    func saveEvent() {
        if EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event) == .authorized{

            let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
            event.title = "sample"
            event.startDate = Date()
            event.endDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(2 * 60 * 60)
            event.isAllDay = false
            event.calendar = self.eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
            do {
                try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
            }
            catch {
                print("Save is failed.")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is:

```
eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: { (granted, error) in
    if (granted) && (error == nil) {
        let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
        event.title = title
        event.startDate = startDate
        event.endDate = endDate
        event.notes = note
        event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
        do {
            try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
        } catch let e as NSError {
            NSLog(e as! String)
            return
        }
    }
})
```